# Which database should we use for our VB.NET project: wamp or mysql

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net, wamp

I'm a bit confused of this and I just want to ask: which one is a better database for our project?

Our project is a library system using bar code and a online website for the reservation of books and for the user to view if the book is available or not...
Both system and website mush have one database.
I just wanted to ask this because I'm confused about these 2 databases.

I already tried using the workbench of `mysql` and people keep saying that I should use sql in `wamp`. But I don't know the difference and what will be the outcome in storing data in our system and web.

Comment: This is very subjective, low in detail (you give virtually no information that would help us tell you which database is best for you) and misleading - WAMP isn't a database, and WAMP uses MySQL, so there isn't much of a choice....

Comment: You are making a serious mistake if you judge technologies by their acronyms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is both subjective and unclear, but I'll try to add some information regardless:

WAMP (Windows, Apache, MySQL, PHP) isn't a database, it's a software stack using mySQL as the database.

By definition, you can't use WAMP (ie PHP) if you're using VB.NET: You're using WIMVB (Windows, IIS, MySQL or another database, and VB)

If you're using .NET, it usually makes sense to complete the Microsoft stack and use SQL Server, making your stack into: Windows, IIS, SQL Server and VB.NET (Although I'd recommend using C#.NET, not VB, as you'll it more widespread while being every bit as capable.

Answer (score -1):

MySql would be a better choice for most applications, in my opinion. It as a good connector for .Net, and will be more flexible down the road. I would be more likely to use WAMP for a simple application with little chance for later enhancements -- a quick one-time app.